# To replace a set of strings in a file with another string in a unix file

Tags: unix

I have a parameter name like

PAR="DBS_OUT"

and I have a text file(Repla.txt) with below values:

DB_TECH

DB_ADMIN

DB_TERA

DB_APS

These values in the files can defer but the parameter value will remain the same.

Now I have some Unix shell script where I need to find all such values mentioned in the file (Repla.txt)
and replace them with the parameter (PAR). Since the values in the Repla.txt is not fixed I am not able to use the sed command. for eg:
sed 's/old/new/g' input.txt > output.txt

Can anyone please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you are trying to do but if you are trying to use the values contained in Repla.txt as the strings that you want to replace in other files then the following bash line will do what you want:

```
PAR="DBS_OUT"; for FIND in `cat Repla.txt`; do $( find /path/to/files -name 'test?.txt' -exec sed -i "s/$FIND/$PAR/g" '{}' \;); done;
```

It will replace the strings contained in Repla.txt with the string DBS_OUT in all files that match test?.txt in the dir (and subdirs) /path/to/files. You will need to understand how find works.

Also note that I am not telling sed to backup, you probably want to test this out on some test files before you execute it for real. Hopefully you also have your scripts in source control so its not a big deal if you mess things up.

Answer (score 0):

I hope your replacement on Capital letters only.

**sed 's/DBS_[A-Z]*/DBS_OUT/g' repla.txt > destination file**

or

**sed 's/DBS_[A-Z]*/DBS_OUT/g' repla.txt**